# How to get access token key from graph api for my facebook page?

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I want to show my facebook page's like on my WordPress website. In my theme option, there is a option for access token key for my facebook page. How can I get my access token key for my facebook page?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
2. Then Choose **Page Access Token** from **Get Token**
3. It will show the list of pages you manage.
4. Choose your desired page to get the **access token key**.

It works like a charm for me.